# Reading strings with spaces from a file

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

I'm working on a project and I just encountered a really annoying problem. I have a file which stores all the messages that my account received. A message is a data structure defined this way:

```
typedef struct _message{
char dest[16]; 
char text[512];
}message;
```

`dest` is a string that cannot contain spaces, unlike the other fields.
Strings are acquired using the `fgets()` function, so `dest` and `text` can have "dynamic" length (from 1 character up to length-1 legit characters). Note that I manually remove the newline character after every string is retrieved from stdin.

The "inbox" file uses the following syntax to store messages:

```
dest
text
```

So, for example, if I have a message from Marco which says "Hello, how are you?" and another message from Tarma which says "Are you going to the gym today?", my inbox-file would look like this:

```
Marco
Hello, how are you?

Tarma
Are you going to the gym today?
```

I would like to read the username from the file and store it in string s1 and then do the same thing for the message and store it in string s2 (and then repeat the operation until EOF), but since `text` field admits spaces I can't really use `fscanf()`.

I tried using `fgets()`, but as I said before the size of every string is dynamic. For example if I use `fgets(my_file, 16, username)` it would end up reading unwanted characters. I just need to read the first string until `\n` is reached and then read the second string until the next `\n` is reached, this time including spaces.

Any idea on how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `fgets` stops at a newline or EOF.  If you have stripped off the new line, don't you already know the precise length of the string?

Comment: The 16 you passed to `fgets()` is the *maximum* length of the string. `fgets()` stops at (16-1) chars or newline or EOF

Comment: @Tony When I retrieve strings from the file, I do not know the exact length, I only know the maximum length a string can have (16 chars for dest, 512 chars for text including the \0) I'm sorry for making myself unclear.

Comment: @Weather Vane You're right. Maybe I should change the syntax I use to write messages inside the file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char username[16];
    char text[512];
    int ch, i;
    FILE *my_file = fopen("inbox.txt", "r");

    while(1==fscanf(my_file, "%15s%*c", username)){
        i=0;
        while (i < sizeof(text)-1 && EOF!=(ch=fgetc(my_file))){
            if(ch == '\n' && i && text[i-1] == '\n')
                break;
            text[i++] = ch;
        }
        text[i] = 0;
        printf("user:%s\n", username);
        printf("text:\n%s\n", text);
    }
    fclose(my_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just have one small doubt about your implementation, does the "%*c" tell the fscanf() to ignore the last character encountered after 15 characters?

Comment: @Toxicroak 15 is  the maximum number of characters to read. it is not always 15 character actually read.
`%*c` to skip the newline after the name.

Answer (score 2):

As the length of each string is dynamic then, if I were you, I would read the file first for finding each string's size and then create a dynamic array of strings' length values.

Suppose your file is:

```
A long time ago
in a galaxy far,
far away....
```

So the first line length is `15`, the second line length is `16` and the third line length is `12`.

Then create a dynamic array for storing these values.

Then, while reading strings, pass as the 2nd argument to `fgets` the corresponding element of the array. Like `fgets (string , arrStringLength[i++] , f);`.

But in this way you'll have to read your file twice, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fgets()` easily enough as long as you're careful.  This code seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAX_MESSAGES = 20 };

typedef struct Message
{
    char dest[16]; 
    char text[512];
} Message;

static int read_message(FILE *fp, Message *msg)
{
    char line[sizeof(msg->text) + 1];
    msg->dest[0] = '\0';
    msg->text[0] = '\0';
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)
    {
        //printf("Data: %zu <<%s>>\n", strlen(line), line);
        if (line[0] == '\n')
            continue;
        size_t len = strlen(line);
        line[--len] = '\0';
        if (msg->dest[0] == '\0')
        {
            if (len < sizeof(msg->dest))
            {
                memmove(msg->dest, line, len + 1);
                //printf("Name: <<%s>>\n", msg->dest);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: name (%s) too long (%zu vs %zu)\n",
                        line, len, sizeof(msg->dest)-1);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (len < sizeof(msg->text))
            {
                memmove(msg->text, line, len + 1);
                //printf("Text: <<%s>>\n", msg->dest);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: text for %s too long (%zu vs %zu)\n",
                        msg->dest, len, sizeof(msg->dest)-1);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    return EOF;
}

int main(void)
{
    Message mbox[MAX_MESSAGES];
    int n_msgs;

    for (n_msgs = 0; n_msgs < MAX_MESSAGES; n_msgs++)
    {
        if (read_message(stdin, &mbox[n_msgs]) == EOF)
            break;
    }

    printf("Inbox (%d messages):\n\n", n_msgs);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_msgs; i++)
        printf("%d: %s\n   %s\n\n", i + 1, mbox[i].dest, mbox[i].text);

    return 0;
}
```

The reading code will handle (multiple) empty lines before the first name, between a name and the text, and after the last name.  It is slightly unusual in they way it decides whether to store the line just read in the `dest` or `text` parts of the message.  It uses `memmove()` because it knows exactly how much data to move, and the data is null terminated.  You could replace it with `strcpy()` if you prefer, but it should be slower (the probably not measurably slower) because `strcpy()` has to test each byte as it copies, but `memmove()` does not.  I use `memmove()` because it is always correct; `memcpy()` could be used here but it only works when you guarantee no overlap.  Better safe than sorry; there are plenty of software bugs without risking extras.  You can decide whether the error exit is appropriate — it is fine for test code, but not necessarily a good idea in production code.  You can decide how to handle '0 messages' vs '1 message' vs '2 messages' etc.

You can easily revise the code to use dynamic memory allocation for the array of messages.  It would be easy to read the message into a simple `Message` variable in `main()`, and arrange to copy into the dynamic array when you get a complete message.  The alternative is to 'risk' over-allocating the array, though that is unlikely to be a major problem (you would not grow the array one entry at a time anyway to avoid quadratic behaviour when the memory has to be moved during each allocation).

If there were multiple fields to be processed for each message (say, date received and date read too), then you'd need to reorganize the code some more, probably with another function.

Note that the code avoids the reserved namespace.  A name such as `_message` is reserved for 'the implementation'.  Code such as this is not part of the implementation (of the C compiler and its support system), so you should not create names that start with an underscore.  (That over-simplifies the constraint, but only slightly, and is a lot easier to understand than the more nuanced version.)

The code is careful not to write any magic number more than once.

Sample output:

```
Inbox (2 messages):

1: Marco
   How are you?

2: Tarma
   Are you going to the gym today?
```

Comment: Very detailed explanation, helped me a lot. Thank you!!